# Проверить существование файла glob php

Tags: php, glob

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код:

```
<?php
foreach (glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/users/'.$_GET['id'].'/passport/*') as $filename) {
    echo basename($filename);
}
?>
```

Как проверить существование файлов в данной папке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php

$arrFiles = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/users/'.$_GET['id'].'/passport/*');

if (!empty($arrFiles)){
  foreach ($arrFiles as $filename) {
       echo basename($filename);
    }
}else{
// Действие если папка пуста или вернулось FALSE
}
```

glob возвращает пустой массив в случае пустой папки, а в случае ошибки FALSE.
Оба этих состояния можно проверить функцией empty();

Comment: Супер, спасибо большое.